# "Drinking number" of a graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, set-theory, infinite-combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

**Motivation.** A while ago I attended a party and I only knew some, but not all, of the attendees. There were 2 kinds of drinks: beer and soda. I noticed that amongst my acquaintances, more than half drank beer. So in order to go against what I perceived as the mainstream ("drink a beer"), I picked a soda. Then I wondered whether a beer / soda mapping to all the guests is possible so that everyone has a drink such that *at least half* of his acquaintances have the *other* drink.

Let's formalize this.

**Formal version.** Let $G=(V,E)$ be a simple, undirected graph (not necessarily finite). For $v\in V$, let $N(v) = \{w\in V: \{v,w\}\in E\}.$

If $\kappa > 0$ is a cardinal, we call a map $d: V \to \kappa$ a "drinking map" if for all $v\in V$ with $N(v) \neq \emptyset$ we have $$|N(v)\cap d^{-1}(\{d(v)\})| \leq |N(v) \setminus d^{-1}(\{d(v)\})|.$$

(We imagine $d(v)$ to be the "drink" that $v$ is having, and $v$ does not want that more than half of her friends are having $d(v)$ as well.)

Let the "drinking number" of $G$ be the smallest cardinal $\kappa$ such that there is a "drinking map" $d: V\to \kappa$, and denote it by $\text{dr}(G)$.

**Question.** Can $\text{dr}(G)$ become arbitrarily large for finite graphs? How about infinite graphs?

Comment: What's an example where $\mathrm{dr}(G)\ge 3$?

Comment: I don't have such an example and would think that $\text{dr}(G) \leq 2$ for finite graphs. I have no idea about infinite graphs concerning the drinking number.

Comment: I found a paper, [Integer programming approach to static monopolies in graphs](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10878-018-0256-z), whose abstract says, "A subset $M$ of vertices of a graph is called a *static monopoly*, if any vertex $v$ outside $M$ has at least $\lceil{1\over 2}\deg(v)\rceil$ neighbors in $M$." So the statement that $\mathrm{dr}(G)\le 2$ for a finite graph $G$ is equivalent to the statement that the vertex set of $G$ can be partitioned into two disjoint static monopolies.

Comment: In human language, you want to color the vertices of a graph so that, for each vertex $v$, at most half the neighbors of $v$ have the same color as $v$. For a finite graph it's quite easy to show that $2$ colors are enough: just tale a $2$-coloring which minimizes the number of edges joining vertices of the same color. (I'm sure this question has been answered more than once on math.stackexchange but I can't find it now.) The answer is probably the same for infinite graphs but I haven't thought about that.

Comment: @bof You should spell out the details and post that as an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Known as unfriendly partition conjecture. Open for countable graphs: http://www.openproblemgarden.org/op/unfriendly_partitions.

Comment: Specifically, according to the link, it is open whether (in the language of the OP) $\mathrm{dr}(G)\leq 2$ for every countably infinite graph $G$. The link explains why for finite graphs $G$ this is easily seen to be true (as also mentioned in the comment of bof above).

Comment: Could you briefly describe the Milner–Shelah uncountable counterexample, so that this won't be a "link-only" answer? Does their counterexample have dr(G) arbitrarily large, or just dr(G)=3?

Comment: Milner and Shelah not only show that there are graphs with no unfriendly 2-partition, they also prove that every graph has an unfriendly 3-partition